# Html form from php array

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Desired Output]I want to display an html form from php array. I want (first name) input  and (Last name) input to be in one row. I have used bootstrap row class but it raps both inputs in separate row like

```
        <div class="row">first name </div>
        <div class="row">Last name </div>
```

I would be thankful, If any one can help me solve this problem !

```
    <?php

        $form = array(

                    'fname' => array(
                        'title' => 'First Name',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'size' => '50',
                    ),

                    'lname' => array(
                        'title' => 'Last Name',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'size' => '50',
                    ),

        'email' => array(
                        'title' => 'Email',
                        'type' => 'email',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'size' => '50',

                    ),
        'submit' => array(
                        'title' => 'Register',
                        'type' => 'submit',
                        'size' => '50',
                        'class' => 'form-control',

                    ),
        )

           ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
    <?php

        foreach ($contact_form as $name => $elements) {

            $label = '<label>' . $elements['title'] . '</label><br>';

            if ($elements['type'] == 'text') {

                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo $label . '<input  type="' . $elements['type'] . '" name="' . $name . '"  size="' . $elements['size'] . '" >';
                echo '</div>';

            } elseif ($elements['type'] == 'email') {
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo $label . '<input type="' . $elements['type'] . '" name="' . $name . '"   size="' . $elements['size'] . '">' . form_error($name) . '<br>';
                echo '</div>';

            }else{

                echo '<input type="' . $elements['type'] . '" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $elements['title'] . '"  size="' . $elements['size'] . '">'  ;
            }
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: _"I have used bootstrap row class but it raps both inputs in separate row like"_ well what do you expect the `row` class to do? You need to use columns http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I want both inputs in one row rather than separate rows

Comment: I have just edited the form same result

Comment: As I said before: _You need to use columns_. Read the documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your PHP array to use Bootstrap sizing instead of percentages. I've also made a couple of other tweaks...

```
$form = [
    [
        'title' => 'First Name',
        'name' => 'first_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'cols' => '6',
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Last Name',
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'cols' => '6',
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Email',
        'name' => 'email',
        'type' => 'email',
        'cols' => '6',
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Register',
        'type' => 'submit',
        'cols' => '6',
    ],
]
```

Then you can use that data to create your form with a foreach loop,

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">

    <?php foreach ($form as $element): ?>

      <div class="col-sm-<?= $element['cols'] ?>">

        <?php if ($element['type'] == 'submit): ?>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><?= $element['title'] ?></button>

        <?php else: ?>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<?= $element['name'] ?>" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?= $element['title'] ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="<?= $element['type'] ?>" class="form-control" id="<?= $element['name'] ?>" name="<?= $element['name'] ?>">
            </div>
          </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

  </form>
</div>
```

Not tested but shouldn't be far off...

Comment: hello Steve ! i have tried this without php foreach loop it works fine but when i use loop it breaks into two rows.

Comment: Re-written answer.

Comment: Thanks a million Steve !

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer if it's answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can manage by conditions.

```
            foreach ($form as $name => $elements) {
            if($name != 'lname'){
            echo '<div class="row">'; 
            }
            // Code here
            if($name != 'lname'){
            echo "</div>"; 
            }
```

}